# 'Unable to find assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.1 In MVC Visual Studio 2017 SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, signalr, sqldependency

'Unable to find assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.1
In SignalR i found this problem **'Unable to find assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.1 in mvc Visula Studio 2017**

in  SqlDependency.Start show error **System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Unable to find assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.'**

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SocketinMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            GetData();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public static IEnumerable<Products> GetData()
        {

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  [id],[back1],[lay1] FROM [SignalrMVC].[dbo].[test33]", connection))
                {
                    // Make sure the command object does not already have
                    // a notification object associated with it.
                    command.Notification = null;
                   SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString);
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                            .Select(x => new Products()
                            {
                                id = x.GetInt32(0),
                                Back1 = x.GetString(1),
                                Lay1 = x.GetString(2)
                            }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        public static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            MyHub.Show();
        }


    }
}
```

connectionStrings

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataBase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-5I7L9G0\SEKHANISQL;Initial Catalog=SignalrMVC;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: upgrade the System.Net.Http     Please find the link for upgrade https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/

Comment: i am using this version System.Net.Http -Version 4.3.4  and it's a latest version  but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

please check your **connection String** in your **web.config** file.
I hope its helfull